# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2002–03'

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, matplotlib, python-datetime

My code works in Jupyter notebook but when I transfer it to a .py file I get an error:
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '2002–03'

Here is the df:

```
Season       Team  GP  GS   MPG   FG%   FT%  BPG   RPG  APG   PPG
0     1989–90    Seattle  81   1  13.8  .479  .736  0.9   4.3  0.3   6.5
1     1990–91    Seattle  81  66  30.1  .508  .661  1.5   8.4  1.8  15.0
2     1991–92    Seattle  64  23  28.3  .504  .748  1.9  10.4  1.3  15.5
3     1992–93    Seattle  78  68  33.1  .492  .712  1.9  10.7  2.0  17.8
4     1993–94    Seattle  79  73  32.9  .538  .741  2.1  10.8  2.6  18.1
5     1994–95    Seattle  82  79  32.7  .547  .749  1.5  10.9  1.8  18.7
6     1995–96    Seattle  79  76  33.3  .561  .742  1.6  11.4  2.2  19.6
7     1996–97    Seattle  81  75  34.0  .510  .742  1.0  10.0  1.9  18.7
8     1997–98  Cleveland  80  80  34.6  .445  .727  1.1   9.3  2.5  20.1
9     1998–99  Cleveland  42  42  35.1  .482  .789  1.1   9.2  2.4  20.5
10  1999–2000  Cleveland  82  82  30.4  .417  .776  1.2   8.8  1.7  17.8
11    2000–01   Portland  68   3  15.9  .407  .771  0.3   3.8  1.0  10.5
12    2001–02   Portland  75   5  16.4  .430  .794  0.4   3.8  0.7   8.1
13    2002–03    Orlando  79  55  20.7  .418  .742  0.4   5.7  0.7   6.8
```

```
PPG = [float(line) for line in df1.PPG]
plt.plot(df1.Season, PPG)
plt.xlabel(r'Seasons')
plt.ylabel(r'Avg Points Per Game')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
```

I would like to create a simple line plot with the df.Season as the x axis

Comment: Your `Season` column is definitely not a datetime column. Try using barchart, which will work for such categorical data.

Comment: @crayxt More precisely a season column, that is, a year column where a year is staggered compared to calendar years, so the two calendar years spanned are mentioned on each row. So 2003–03 means from some date in 2002 until the same date a year later, in 2003, exclusive.